How to reset [maxDate] [minDate] in p-calendar
Issue Description
I'm working with PrimeNG's p-calendar component in my Angular application. I have two date pickers: one for selecting a start date and another for selecting an end date. The end date picker should not allow selecting dates that are before the start date plus one day, and vice versa. To achieve this, I use the maxDate property on the start date picker and the minDate property on the end date picker.
Here is the relevant code for the components:
HTML:
<div class="field">
  <p-calendar
    inputId="startDt"
    formControlName="startDt"
    (onSelect)="setEndDate()"
    [maxDate]="startMaxDate"
  ></p-calendar>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <p-calendar
    inputId="endDt"
    formControlName="endDt"
    (onSelect)="setStartDate()"
    [minDate]="endMinDate"
  ></p-calendar>
</div>

TypeScript:
startMaxDate!: any; //change from Date type
endMinDate!: any;//change from Date type

setEndDate() {
  const startDateValue = this.form.get('startDt')?.value;
  if (startDateValue) {
    this.endMinDate = new Date(startDateValue.getTime());
    this.endMinDate.setDate(this.endMinDate.getDate() + 1);
  } 
}

setStartDate() {
  const endDateValue = this.form.get('endDt')?.value;
  if (endDateValue) {
    this.startMaxDate = new Date(endDateValue.getTime());
    this.startMaxDate.setDate(this.startMaxDate.getDate() - 1);
  } 
}

clearSearchCondition() {
  this.form.reset();
  this.dataSearch = [];
  this.showTable = false;
  this.startMaxDate = new Date(); // Resets to the current date
  this.endMinDate = new Date();   // Resets to the current date
}


Problem
When the clearSearchCondition() method is called, it resets the form and sets startMaxDate and endMinDate to the current date. Despite these changes, the p-calendar components continue to disable dates based on the previous maxDate and minDate values. It seems like the calendar components do not update their date constraints as expected when the form is cleared.
What I Need Help With
I need assistance with ensuring that the maxDate and minDate properties of the p-calendar components are correctly reset when the form data is cleared. Specifically, I’m looking for:

How to force the p-calendar components to refresh or reinitialize their date constraints when clearSearchCondition() is executed.

Any additional steps or best practices to ensure that the date pickers reflect the updated maxDate and minDate values after clearing the form.


Additional Information

I am using PrimeNG version 16.9.1

The calendar components should allow selecting any date after resetting the constraints.


Thank you for your help!

I solve it by change type Date to Any in line
startMaxDate!: any; endMinDate!: any; 
it's works

Set the dates to null this will enable all the dates for the datepicker and is ready for accepting any inputs.
startMaxDate!: Date | null;
endMinDate!: Date | null;
...

...
clearSearchCondition() {
    this.form.reset();
    // this.dataSearch = [];
    // this.showTable = false;
    this.startMaxDate = null; // Resets to the current date
    this.endMinDate = null; // Resets to the current date
}

Stackblitz Demo

I do like you but i have an error  "Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Date'."
at line :
this.startMaxDate = null;this. endMinDate = null;

@SP08AL updated my answer!
